# vs code not integrating with AVD Emulators

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I replaced flutter folder with an older version then Visual Studio Code stopped showing available devices ("No device" not clickable) when I click to run my app so I have to manually start the emulator on Android Studio (AVD) for Visual Studio Code to connect. Before the downgrade everything worked fine and I didn't have to open android studio for Visual Studio Code to connect to emulators.

flutter doctor :

```
C:\Users\Workstudio>flutter doctor
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928], locale en-US)
    
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    [√] VS Code, 32-bit edition (version 1.57.1)
    [!] Connected device
        ! No devices available
    
    ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Things I've tried:

- Reinstall HAXM.
- `adb server-kill`  & `adb server-start`
- checked environmental variables(paths & Android home).
- Updating Android SDK.

Comment: on terminal `flutter emulators`, then `flutter emulators --launch deviceName`

Comment: None worked. I guess I have to open avd from android studio manually anytime I want it to run an app on vs code.

Comment: did you create any emulator-device?